# cassnadra multi/single partition batch explanation

Tags: cassandra

I red the cassandra docs about Good use of BATCH statement -
[single partition batch example](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html)
I want to understand about multi/single partition batch.

According to the docs this is a single partition batch.

```
CREATE TABLE cycling.cyclist_expenses ( 
  cyclist_name text, 
  balance float STATIC, 
  expense_id int, 
  amount float, 
  description text, 
  paid boolean, 
  PRIMARY KEY (cyclist_name, expense_id) 
);

BEGIN BATCH

  INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_expenses (cyclist_name, expense_id, amount, description, paid) VALUES ('Vera ADRIAN', 2, 13.44, 'Lunch', true);

  INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_expenses (cyclist_name, expense_id, amount, description, paid) VALUES ('Vera ADRIAN', 3, 25.00, 'Dinner', false);

...
APPLY BATCH;
```

First partition is - 'Vera ADRIAN', 2
Second partition - 'Vera ADRIAN', 3

Could u explain pls why is it single partition batch?

In another docs I found the example of multi partition batch:

```
Create table shopping_chart 
(cart_id UUID,item_id UUID,price Decimal, total Decimal static,
primary key ((cart_id),item_id));

insert into shopping_chart(cart_id,item_id,price,total) 
values (ABC12345,ABCITEM12345,0.01,0.01);

Begin Batch
insert into shopping_chart(cart_id,item_id,price) values ( ABC12345,ABCITEM123451,1.00);

insert into shopping_chart(cart_id,item_id,price) values ( ABC12345,ABCITEM1234512,2.00);

Update …. cart_id=ABC12345 IF total =0.01;
Apply Batch;
```

And I can’t understand why it's a multi partition batch? Could u pls explain ? There is working only with one partition = ABC12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First partition is - `'Vera ADRIAN', 2` Second partition - `'Vera ADRIAN', 3`
>
> Could u explain pls why is it single partition batch?

Sure.  Because the `expense_id` is not part of the partition key.  Therefore, `Vera ADRIAN` is the same partition key value used in both `INSERT`s.

For the 2nd part of your question, you're right in that the 2nd example does not appear to be a multi-partition query as the `cart_id`s are the same.  Following your link above, I quickly found a bad use of `BATCH` (multi-partition): https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatchBadExample.html

Answer (score 0):

The single-partition batch is when your queries are targeting the same partitions - in this case, Cassandra packs all queries into a single operation (also called "mutation").

The description of second example is incorrect - it's still single-partition batch.